# How do I revive the Magic Mouse after replacing batteries?

Tags: mouse

When I replace the batteries in my Magic Mouse, I turn the mouse off, replace batteries and turn the mouse back on. The problem is that the system does not notice the mouse after this procedure, the mouse cursor stays stuck. I have to put the computer to sleep and wake it again to make the mouse work. Is there a better way to “wake” the mouse, maybe using some keyboard shortcut or a special click combination?

Comment: For me, usually just a normal click of any kind is enough to get it to reconnect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple click should do it. I find that it takes a second sometimes to reconnect so I usually click and move the mouse side to side until I see the mouse cursor move.

Here is the official document from Apple:

> If you turn your mouse or trackpad off
>   or turn off the Bluetooth option in
>   your computer, the connection between
>   the computer and the mouse or trackpad
>   will be lost. When you turn on the
>   mouse or trackpad and Bluetooth, you
>   can re-establish this connection by
>   simply clicking the mouse button or
>   trackpad surface.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3081

Comment: Somehow this did not work for me at least once or twice. Will try again next time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find that double-clicking on both sides of the mouse simultaneously usually causes it to re-pair.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my batteries, and could not get the mouse to restart.  I was befuddled for a while, but then after looking closely at the battery compartment, I realized that the 2 batteries go in the SAME direction, not opposite directions as in most electronics.  Problem solved! LOL!

Comment: In the question he said that putting the computer to sleep and waking it resolved the problem. If he put the batteries in wrong, that wouldn't have worked, so this is not his problem.